# nodejs - npm install https, not working

Tags: node.js, https

```js
C:\wamp\www\node-node-node>npm install https
npm ERR! 404 404 Not Found: https
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 'https' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, or http url, or git url.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "https"
npm ERR! cwd C:\wamp\www\node-node-node
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\wamp\www\node-node-node\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I am getting this, so where am I going wrong with the usage?

Comment: You don't need to install `https`. It's a [npm core module](http://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https). You just have to require it in your app.

Comment: does that mean [API's here](http://nodejs.org/api/) can be used just by `var api = require("respective api");` ?

Comment: Yes. All npm core modules have to be used without installation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Node.JS has built in module to create http server and https server. You dont have to install https using npm, but can start using it directly. https existed before npm.

```
var https = require("https"); 
var app = https.createServer(); 
//Rest of the code goes here
```